# JBoss AS7 LinkageError for HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory() method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I'm creating a Spring MVC and Hibernate/JPA web application and I'm having problems with the configuring the application and jboss-deployment descriptor so that I can delegate Persistence management over to my web application instead of JBoss AS7. 
I'm developing for JavaEE7, Spring 4.2.2-Final, and Hibernate 4.3.11.

This is the content of my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure >
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
        <module name="javaee.api" />
        <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javaee.api">
            <imports>
                <exclude path="javax/persistence" />
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Using this I was able to get passed my initial problem of AS7 relying upon its default hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar and use the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.jar deployed with my web app.

However, I'm now getting this error when starting my web app through the admin console.

```
12:56:48,885 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mis-dashboard]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 230) JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider have different Class objects for the type erFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory; used in the signature
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:93) [spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048) [spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:825) [spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

12:56:48,901 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.compiler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 230) JBWEB005025: Parent
```

From what the exception is stating apparently there is a conflict for Jboss ModuleClassLoader for the javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory class. I thought that the entries in my deploy-descriptor would have prevented this but obviously that is not the case.

I'm an experienced software engineer with some experience with Application Server administration but honestly, only enough to be dangerous. Typically, I would rely on a Server Admin team but there is no such team here.

Does anybody have any experience with this or a similar situation?
Any ideas on how I can fix this LinkageError and resolve the conflict?

thank you in advance,

mbeddedsoft

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with JBoss EAP 6.4, Spring 4.2.4, and Hibernate 4.3.11.

I was using the following  jboss-deployment-structure.xml and was able to deploy my web application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="javax/persistence" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However I had a similar LinkageError issue to yours each time I was redeploying the webapp.
After implementing Workaround 2 described here, everything works has expected: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-209.